# Ethernet is disabling WiFi

Tags: routing, wifi, ethernet

We are working in iMX6 board running in Yocto 4.9.88 build.  It has both Wifi and Ethernet connections. When we connected WiFi alone, pinging is working properly. Pinging works if we connect Ethernet.  When we disconnected Ethernet, WiFi still gets an IP and shows it is connected, but we are not able to ping.

Wifi has network metric as 10 while Ethernet has 0. Below are the routing tables for the different instances.

When WiFi alone is connected,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

When WiFi + Ethernet is connected,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
202.83.21.25    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
202.83.21.43    192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

When Ethernet is disconnected, but WiFi is still connected,

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Why is Ethernet removing wlan0 entries too in routing table and is it possible for both the interfaces to work without any constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix is to re-add the missing route towards wlan0.

The longer story:

The behavior is generally normal and logical (except one thing, which may be a bug or miss-configuration).

When you are on WiFi and you connect Ethernet, the administrative distance changes so that Ethernet has priority. That's what these 2 lines mean:

```
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0
```

Metric 0 means highest priority. Metric 10 will be on stand-by as long as you have eth0 active and working. If you disconnect cable/eth0, then wlan0 becomes main connection again.

So far so good, but if when you disconnect the wired and the routing

`0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    10     0        0 wlan0`

is gone, then you of course have a connectivity problem, no longer having an actual route.
You may bypass this by adding a gateway of last resort.

If you configure multiple networks as candidate default routes using the `ip default-network command`, the network that has the lowest administrative distance is chosen as the network for the gateway of last resort. If all the networks have the same administrative distance then the network listed first in the routing table (`show ip route`) is chosen as the network for the gateway of last resort. If you use both the `ip default-network` and `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` commands to configure candidate default networks, and the network used by the `ip default-network` command is known statically, the network defined with the i`p default-network` command takes precedence and is chosen for the gateway of last resort. Otherwise if the network used by the `ip default-network` command is derived by a routing protocol, the `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` command, which has a lower administrative distance, takes precedence and is chosen for the gateway of last resort. If you use multiple `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0` commands to configure a default route, traffic is load-balanced over the multiple routes and will work on any of the 2 when one of them is up.

You may choose which situation is best-fit in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to create a bond interface over both interfaces. Disable IP addresses on both interfaces and configure the bond interface as you need it.

You will always have the same IP and it will use the interfaces as they are available.

Comment: We had GPRS interface also in same board. GPRS also pings when connected alone, fails once ethernet is connected and reamoved. Is it possible to have bonded interface over GPRS too?. How to disable IP of GPRS interface?

Comment: The GPRS interface should have a completely different network and should neither affect the bond nor be affected by it. Adding it to the bond will not work because your internal IP address will not work on the GPRS interface.